# Combine few queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written 4 queries , 
all of the are showing the details of one column which is [Source]

I need to combine this queries together so the result will be Shawn in one table with all the results per each [Source] (like 1 table with all the results, without duplicate parameters)

Thanks a lot . 
 The Queries :

1)

```
SELECT  [Source] ,
        COUNT (DISTINCT ROW_ID ) AS 'Number Of Contacts'
FROM [SRL-TST].[dbo].[TBL_SRL_Contacts]
GROUP BY [Source]
```

2)

```
SELECT [Source] , 
       COUNT (DISTINCT ROW_ID ) AS 'FULL'
FROM dbo.TBL_SRL_Contacts
WHERE Email IS NOT NULL 
AND Company IS NOT NULL
AND Privetphone IS NOT NULL
AND Secondphone IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY [Source]
```

3)

```
SELECT [Source] , 
       COUNT (DISTINCT ROW_ID ) AS 'PARTLY'
FROM dbo.TBL_SRL_Contacts
WHERE Email IS NOT NULL 
OR Company IS NOT NULL
OR Privetphone IS NOT NULL
OR Secondphone IS NOT NULL
```

GROUP BY [Source]

4)

```
SELECT [Source] , 
       COUNT(DISTINCT ROW_ID ) AS 'MISSING'
FROM dbo.TBL_SRL_Contacts
WHERE Email IS  NULL 
AND Company IS  NULL
AND Privetphone IS  NULL
AND Secondphone IS  NULL
GROUP BY [Source]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT [Source] ,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ROW_ID ) AS [Number Of Contacts],
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Email IS NOT NULL AND Company IS NOT NULL AND Privetphone IS NOT NULL AND Secondphone IS NOT NULL
                  THEN ROW_ID
             END) as [Full],
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Email IS NOT NULL OR Company IS NOT NULL OR Privetphone IS NOT NULL OR Secondphone IS NOT NULL
                  THEN ROW_ID
             END) as [Partly]
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Email IS  NULL AND Company IS  NULL AND Privetphone IS  NULL AND Secondphone IS  NULL
                  THEN ROW_ID
             END) as [Missing]
FROM [SRL-TST].[dbo].[TBL_SRL_Contacts]
GROUP BY [Source];
```